# fix resizing div gap in flex container

Tags: html, css

**The website is responsive but when resizing the navigation div it creates a big gap spacing which i don't want and would like to create a handle instead of corner button . the current website to test is https://test.alexhernandez11.repl.co and would love something similar to this website http://jsfiddle.net/6q27j3kz/**

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400&display=swap");

/* SET UP */

body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  resize: both;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Task 3.2 */

.task-3-2.container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100vh;
  gap: 5px;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto auto auto;
  grid-template-areas: "header" "nav" "main" "sidebar" "ads" "footer";
}

.task-3-2 .header {
  grid-area: header;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.task-3-2 .navigation {
  grid-area: nav;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

.task-3-2 .ads {
  grid-area: ads;
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}

.task-3-2 .sidebar {
  grid-area: sidebar;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  resize: horizontal;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.task-3-2 .main {
  grid-area: main;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.task-3-2 .footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 720px) {
  .task-3-2.container {
    grid-template-areas: "header header header" "nav nav nav" "sidebar main main" "ads footer footer";
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1020px) {
  .task-3-2.container {
    grid-template-areas: "header header header header" "sidebar nav nav ads" "sidebar main main ads" "footer footer footer footer";
    grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="task-3-2 container">
  <div id='handle' class="item header">header</div>

  <div id='handle' class="item navigation">navigation</div>

  <div id='handle' class="item main">main</div>

  <div id='handle' class="item sidebar">sidebar</div>

  <div id='handle' class="item ads">ads</div>

  <div id='handle' class="item footer">footer</div>
</div>
```